# insert two section at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here I am trying to insert the `Sections 1` and `Section 3` as soon as address get filled in `Section 2`. Initially they must be hidden or still not inserted in table view. I get success in inserting the `Section 3` but unable to insert `Section 2`. Here is my piece of code after address get filled in `Section 2`.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  [self.reviewOrderList insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:3] 
  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
  [self.reviewOrderList reloadData];

 }
```

[image]

Comment: Once a value is entered into the textField change the dataSource of tableView and reload it.

Comment: make custom prototype cell.

Comment: @Anupdas yes, but how initially i hide section 1 before filling address. Actually i got address from some other controller and pass in to section 3.

Comment: @JitendraDeore can i have some sample code of custom prototype cell. i am not known to it.

Comment: try to use storyboard and drag and drop the prototype cell.. First drag the TableView ane then tablviewcell  in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of `NSMutableIndexSet` and add the indexes of the sections you want to add. Then you can pass that indexSet in `-[UITableView insertSections:withRowAnimation:]`. You DON'T need to call `-[UITableView reloadData]` right after: the insert method automatically does what's needed to display the new sections. You could even batch multiple changes and animate them at once by calling `-[UITableView beginUpdates]` before making the changes and finalizing the changes by calling `-[UITableView endUpdates]`.

For more informations checkout the [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Well, i do not get it exactly. Flow is like, firstly i need only one section i.e section 2. After getting address from other view controller or when i return back to screen (the one i have attached above) it should show two section section 1 and section 3.

Comment: whatever i did is in method ViewWillAppear. I got the section 3 but not section 1. Here, in image the section 1 is already there when i alloc and init this controller.